# Whats wrong with my code for downloading files in php?

Tags: php, download

`download.php`:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connection_psfriend.php'); ?>
<?php
$idreceived = addslashes($_REQUEST['sendid']);

$filepathquery = "SELECT bd_brushfilepath FROM tbl_brushdescription WHERE bd_brushid = $idreceived";
$Recordset = mysql_query($filepathquery,$connection_psfriend) or die(mysql_error());
$filepath = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset);
$receivedfilerequest = $filepath['bd_brushfilepath'];
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'ps-friend'.'/' . $receivedfilerequest;

$updatedownlaodquery = "UPDATE tbl_brushdescription SET bd_brushdownloads = bd_brushdownloads + 1 WHERE bd_brushid = $idreceived";
$Recordset = mysql_query($updatedownlaodquery,$connection_psfriend) or die(mysql_error());
if(file_exists( $file_path)){

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_path));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_path);
exit;
```

}

My problem:

The code works fine with google Chrome for all 143 entries made in the database. It works fine fine with Firefox too except for 5 out of those 143.

for firefox it shows:( for those 5 entries):[image]

In the database, I am using filepaths to store the files. All the files are either in zip format or rar format. Those files are not downloaded in rar/zip format. With google chrome, there is no problem at all. Is there something wrong with the script?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You shoukd set the correct mimetype, at the line `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` you are setting, in fact, the mimetype appearing on that download dialog.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the `Content-Type` to `application/zip` or `application/rar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please stop using `MYSQL_` function, see [why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Secondly you are using `$idreceived = addslashes($_REQUEST['sendid']);` as a nice way to prevent SQL injection. Unfortunately you are calling the query like `WHERE bd_brushid = $idreceived`, so without quotes.

In other words, you are still vulnerable, as long as I dont use any quotes. Consider me sending `sendid=1 OR 1=1`. All your rows would be updated in the second query.

Change it to `WHERE bd_brushid = '$idreceived'`, or even better: check [how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Now to your problem. I think you should change one line to the following to include quotes

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
```

If it still does not work, send the right content type in the header.

```
<?php

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);

header('Content-Type: '.$type)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following has always worked for me

```
$file=$_POST['file'];
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file" );
readfile("$_POST[file]");
```

without any of the content type headers.However my file extension is `.zip`.Your file does not seem to have an extension.